# declaring/initializing primitives equal to creating new objects

Tags: java, object, initialization, primitive, declare

is declaring/initializing primitives the same as creating new objects? from what i know when we create primitives, we also creating wrapper classes for them. im implementing on java btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, assigning primitive values does **not** create any objects.

What you **might** be referring to is the fact that primitive values can be auto-boxed into the corresponding wrappers, when they are used in a context where a reference type (a.k.a "an object") is required:

```
int i = 13;     // this line does not create an object
Integer i2 = i; // at this line 13 is auto-boxed into an Integer object

char c = 'x';   // again: no object created:
List<Character> l = new ArrayList<Character>();
l.add(c);       // c is auto-boxed into a Character object
```

Also, I'll try to describe the difference between declare and initialize:

```
int i;          // an int-variable is declared
int j = 0;      // an int-variable is declared and initialized
i = 1;          // an int-variable is assigned a value, this is *not* initialization
```

A variable is "declared" when it is created for the first time (i.e. you specify the type and name of the variable). It is initialized when it's assigned a value *during declaration*.

Answer (score 3):

No, declaring and initializing a primitive variable does *not* create an object. Let's take a class with two integer values - one using the wrapper type and one not.

```
public class Foo
{
    private int primitive = 10;
    private Integer wrapper = new Integer(10);
}
```

The *value* of the `primitive` variable is just the number 10. The value of the `wrapper` variable is a *reference* to an `Integer` object which in turn contains the number 10. So an instance of `Foo` would keep state for the number in `primitive` and the reference in `wrapper`.

There *are* wrapper classes for all primitive types in Java, but you don't use them automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a primitive **DOES NOT** also create a wrapper class for them.

As for your original question: Declaring/initializing a primitive will create it on the stack, whereas declaring an object will allocate a variable to hold a reference to an object. Initializing the object will allocate it on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: No.

Check this out:  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 0):

No. Primitives are not objects in java.